# Unable to start/stop an AI Platform Notebook Instance in AI Platform but Able to in Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am setting up permissions for users to use a pre-created AI Platform VM instance in GCP AI Platform. I have created a custom role with permissions

```
compute.acceleratorTypes.list
compute.diskTypes.list
compute.instances.list
compute.instances.start
compute.instances.stop
compute.machineTypes.list
compute.subnetworks.list
iam.serviceAccounts.actAs
notebooks.environments.get
notebooks.environments.getIamPolicy
notebooks.environments.list
notebooks.instances.get
notebooks.instances.getIamPolicy
notebooks.instances.list
notebooks.locations.get
notebooks.locations.list
notebooks.operations.get
notebooks.operations.list
resourcemanager.projects.get
```

The user can start and stop the instance from the Compute Engine section of the GCP console, but *not* from the AI Platform section.  When I try in the latter, I get the error:

```
sample-ai-platform-vm: Permission 'notebooks.instances.start' denied on 'projects/test-project/locations/us-east1-b/instances/sample-ai-platform-vm'
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following permissions:

```
notebooks.instances.start
notebooks.instances.stop
```

You can take a look at the Notebooks Admin role for reference:

https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/iam

Comment: Thank you. Figured this out yesterday. Did not realize that the new Notebooks API created change in permission requirements.